# Can't change a model field type in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model **ReservationSupplement**:

```
class ReservationSupplement(models.Model):
    reservation_hotel = models.ForeignKey(ReservationHotel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='supplements', verbose_name=_("Hotel Supplements"))
    supplement = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

And I want to change it to:

```
class ReservationSupplement(models.Model):
    reservation_hotel = models.ForeignKey(ReservationHotel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='supplements', verbose_name=_("Hotel Supplements"))
    supplement = models.ForeignKey('RatesManagerApp.Product', on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='reservations', verbose_name=_("Supplement"))
```

I had no problem with the `makemigrations`, but when I run `migrate`, I get this error: `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "supplement" does not exist`.

I don't know what causes it because the traceback only gives me Django modules and no clue of what causes the error to arise.

Comment: what is RatesManagerApp.Product? like ReservationHotel it should be another model to make it a Foreign key

Comment: Of course, it is another model.

Comment: step1. delete `supplement` field from model and do migration. step2. add `supplement` field with FK and do migration

Comment: supplement is not connecting with any model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Things to check:**

1. Copy any important data first, then delete your migrations folder inside that app.
2. If you intend to use an app_name path with the model in your [`ForeignKey`,](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) it has to be like `'app_name.ModelName'`. So make sure your app_name has the proper case sensitivity if you want to use it like that *(though you should make it all lowercase except for the `Product`, because the way you have it makes it look like a Model within a Model, which is possible hence the `ForeignKey`, but not a good convention when specifying paths)*.